# SELECT GROUP with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this table below and want to get the min value of quantity, max value of quantity, first value of quantity and last value of quantity. The new table should be grouped by date with a 1 day interval.

```
id  item    quantity    date
1   xLvCm   2           2020-01-10 19:15:03
1   UBizL   4           2020-01-10 20:16:41
1   xLvCm   1           2020-01-10 21:21:12
1   xLvCm   3           2020-01-11 11:14:00
1   UBizL   1           2020-01-11 15:01:10
1   moJEe   4           2020-01-12 00:15:50
1   moJEe   1           2020-01-12 02:11:23
1   UBizL   1           2020-01-12 04:16:17
1   KiZoX   3           2020-01-13 10:10:02
1   KiZoX   2           2020-01-13 19:05:40
1   KiZoX   1           2020-01-13 20:14:33
```

This is the expected table result

```
min(quantity)   max(quantity)   first(quantity) last(quantity)    date
1               4               2               1                 2020-01-10 19:15:03
1               3               3               1                 2020-01-11 11:14:00
1               4               4               1                 2020-01-12 00:15:50
1               4               3               1                 2020-01-13 10:10:02
```

The SQL query I have tried is 
 `SELECT MIN(quantity), MAX(quantity), FIRST(quantity), LAST(quantity) FROM tablename GROUP BY date`

I can't figure out how to include the first and last values of quantity and group by day (like 10, 11, 12, 13) instead of date like (2020-01-10 19:15:03)

Comment: use date function to return date from datetime eg date(date). date is not a reserved word but I would avoid giving column names this value for clarity and in your case it's not a meaningful name given the data is datetime

Comment: For group by day you can use `GROUP BY DAY(date);`. About first and last value you can use window functions added in MySQL 8.0, or more complicated query in older MySQL versions.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to state the database tool you are using because of the different functionality available in each of them.  But if you were using Snowflake this is something I would try:

```
select distinct day(date) as day_of_month,
       min(quantity) over (partition by day(date) order by date range between unbounded preceding and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) min_quantity, 
       max(quantity) over (partition by day(date) order by date range between unbounded preceding and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) max_quantity ,
       last_value(QUANTITY) over (partition by day(date) order by date range BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) as last_quantity,  
       first_value(QUANTITY) over (partition by day(date) order by date range BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) as first_quantity
from demo_db.staging.test
```

It is important to note that this is a costly query.  If your table is huge this might take too long.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to this problem is to use window functions and aggregation.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT date(date), MIN(quantity), MAX(quantity),
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_a = 1 THEN quantity END) as first_quantity,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_d = 1 THEN quantity END) as last_quantity
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date(date) ORDER BY date) as seqnum_a,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date(date) ORDER BY date des) as seqnum_d
      FROM tablename t
     ) t
GROUP BY date(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select A.minquantity,A.maxquantity,B.firstquantity,C.lastquantity,A.date from (
    (select min(quantity) as minquantity,max(quantity) as maxquantity,Date(date) as date 
    from Test group by Date(date))A
    join 
    (select Date(date) as date,quantity as firstquantity from 
    Test where date in (select min(date) from Test group by Date(date)))B
    on A.date=B.date
    join 
    (select Date(date)as date,quantity as lastquantity from Test 
    where date in (select max(date) from Test group by Date(date)))C
    on A.date=C.date
    );
```

Output:

```
1   4   2   1   2020-01-10
1   3   3   1   2020-01-11
1   4   4   1   2020-01-12
1   3   3   1   2020-01-13
```